# verbatim inside subfloat?

Tags: subfloats, verbatim

When I write the following

```
\subfloat[caption]{\label{fig:xxxx}\verb+xxxx+}
```

I get `\verb illegal in command argument`. Seems that isn't possible to define a `verbatim` environment inside a `\subfloat`.

When I use `\subfloat[caption]{\label{fig:xxxx}\texttt{xxxx}}` it works, but I need multiple lines, so I have to use `verbatim`

What alternatives do I have? Maybe another package?

Comment: If you don't really need verbatim mode and `\texttt` is sufficient, then `\parbox{5cm}{\ttfamily text}` will do. Adjust the dimension. Otherwise you should present an example.

Comment: If you need multiple lines, `\verb` won't get you far. Does `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` work?

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A package [`alltt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/alltt) might be useful.

Comment: You could use the `subfigure` environment, offered by the/my `subcaption` package. `\verb+xxxx+` will work here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `\verb` in the argument to another command. If you really need verbatim mode in your subfloat, then something like

```
\newsavebox{\verbbox} % in the preamble

\begin{lrbox}{\verbbox}
\verb+xxxx+
\end{lrbox}%
\subfloat[caption]{\label{myfigure}\usebox{\verbbox}}
```

will do. Inside the `lrbox` you can also put a `minipage`, for longer verbatim snippets:

```
\begin{lrbox}{\verbbox}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
Some verbatim
on more than one line
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}%
\subfloat[caption]{\label{myfigure}\usebox{\verbbox}}
```

The `subcaption` package has features similar to `subfig` and subfloats are realized as environments, where verbatim is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

See Section 6.9 ("How do I put a verbatim environment in a sub-ﬂoat?") of [the manual of the Subﬁg package](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf). Basically, the manual suggests that you define the `SubFloat` environment in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newbox\sf@box
\newenvironment{SubFloat}[2][]%
{\def\sf@one{#1}%
\def\sf@two{#2}%
\setbox\sf@box\hbox
\bgroup}%
{ \egroup
\ifx\@empty\sf@two\@empty\relax
\def\sf@two{\@empty}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\sf@one\@empty\relax
\subfloat[\sf@two]{\box\sf@box}%
\else
\subfloat[\sf@one][\sf@two]{\box\sf@box}%
\fi}
\makeatother
```

Then, use the `SubFloat` environment as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{SubFloat}[Black box]{\label{fig:label1}Caption 1.}%
\rule{4cm}{3cm}%...blackbox subfigure...
\end{SubFloat}%
\hspace{1.5cm}%
\begin{SubFloat}{\label{fig:label2}Caption 2.}%...verbatim subfigure with
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}% a minipage to control the width...
\begin{verbatim}
abc def ghi jkl
xx x xxx
abc def ghi jkl
\end{verbatim}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{SubFloat}
\caption{Main Caption.}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: No, while it's in the manual of a package, this is _not_ the way to solve this problem - it's a very crude hack.